# VBA delete rows before today's date

Tags: vba, excel

I have a csv file on excel that is ~CU for the column.

And the row gets keep updated (as of now it's 2606).

I'm trying to

1. delete all row that are `before today's date` as recorded on column D
2. no typing/text box/human input for today's date.

[image]

```
Sub deleterows()
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 4).Value < *numeric value* Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `*numeric value*` with `Date`.

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for reply! How can i set it as the last date of the record??

Comment: Do you mean something by "before today's date" other than "before today's date"?  If so, what do you mean by "today's date"?

Comment: let's say today's date is 1/3/2017, then I want all rows with before 1/3/2017 to be deleted e.g. 12/31/2016, 1/4/2016 :)

Comment: That's exactly what `If Cells(i, 4).Value < Date Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete` ***does***.

Comment: as I run this code, I want every row except 1/4/2017 to be deleted! :) Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for the comment! I think both you and cyboashu is correct! Sorry for my stupidity. I forgot to use updated excel file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For dates (and currency), its always recommended to use `Value2` instead of `Value`.

MSDN:

> The only difference between this property and the Value property is
>   that the Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date data types.
>   You can return values formatted with these data types as
>   floating-point numbers by using the Double data type.

So all you need to do is change this part `If Cells(i, 4).Value < *numeric value* Then`

With this `If Cells(i, 4).Value2 < Date Then`

and it evaluate as true if Column D is older than today.

Comment: Hi, as a follow-up, when i executed the code, It deletes everything except the first row of the file.

Comment: looking at ur screenshot all dates are older than today, so it will delete the rows. Do you have anyy dates for or beyond today.

Comment: nope. 1/3/2017 is the latest date! Also, A B  1/4/2016   C

is what i got for executing your code: which is the first row of the file.

Comment: 1. First row will never be touched irrespective of date as your For Loop terminates at Row 2. |||| 2. Put down a date for 1/4/2017 (yes its 2017 now  :)) in any of the Rows and see if it gets deleted. Most likely it won't.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I forgot to use updated excel file. Sorry for my stupidity. Thank you again!

Comment: is there anyway that i can loop to delete the first row as well? @cyboashu sorry for the follow up..

Comment: change this `lastrow To 2 ` to `lastrow To 1`

Comment: changed to For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1!